# How to use SQL statement given below in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How do I use the SQL given below in codeigniter?

```
select * 
from  borrow_book 
where isbn=(select isbn
            from add_book 
            where author='$author)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = $this->db
->select("*")
->from("borrow_book")
->where("isbn=(select isbn from add_book where author='".$this->db->escape_str($author)."')",NULL,false)
->get();
```

i just want to add, i'm not familiar with your DB Structure but i think most of the time a Join would be better than a subselect

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
$query= $this->db->query("SELECT borrow_book.* 
                            FROM borrow_book, add_book
                            WHERE borrow_book.isbn= add_book.isbn AND add_book.author = '$author'");
$result= $query->result_array();
return $result;
```